# How to count number of zeros in the character table of a finite group by GAP?

Tags: representation-theory, characters, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I am trying to write a function in GAP to count the number of zeros in the character table of a finite group. And I have a problem counting zeros.

```
Numberofzeros := function(group)

local c, irr, zeros, x, numberofzeros; 

c := CharacterTable(group);
irr := Irr(c);
zeros:=[];


for x in irr do 
zeros := Union(zeros, Positions(x, 0)); 
od;
zeros := AsSet(zeros);

numberofzeros:=Size(zeros);

return(numberofzeros); 
end;
```

The function Positions caused losing some zeros while counting.

Here is another code.

```
gap>g:=SymmetricGroup(4);

gap>L:=List(ConjugacyClasses(g),c->Representative(c));

gap>c:=CharacterTable(g);

gap>irr:=Irr(g);

gap>zeros:=[];

gap>for 1<=i,j<=Size(L) do if L[i]^irr[j]=0 then Add(zeros,(i,j)); fi; od; #(*)#

gap>Size(zeros);
```

The line (*) doesn't work. I don't know where the mistakes are.

Any suggestions are preferred.

Comment: You can set code off from the text and preserve its line breaks verbatim by enclosing it in ```.

Comment: Assuming that `c` is your character table, `Sum(Irr(c),x->Number(x,IsZero));` will give you the count.

Comment: I see your point. You take an irreducible character and if it takes 0 value in the character table then you count one. Thanks very much! I also would like to understand how to choose characters of special degree. For example, given a prime 3, I would like to find all characters with degree coprime to 3.  @ahulpke

Comment: @user44312. `Filtered(Irr(c),x->1=Gcd(x[1],3))` since the first entry of a character is the degree

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience! @ahulpke

Comment: Please format the code next time (use the `{}` button or backticks). If the answer is contained here in the comments, consider answering your own post so that other users can find the answer clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `c` is your character table, `Sum(Irr(c),x->Number(x,IsZero));` will give you the count of zeroes in the table.